# How to pass individual jinja variable in a jinja loop to python function as a parameter?

Tags: python, html, jinja2

I want to pass an individual jinja variable inside of a jinja loop to a python function as a parameter. In this case, I need to pass {{ book.isbn }} inside of a jinja loop, to a python function in order to use this value.

I have tried to use href="{{ url_for(...) }}" but it only triggers when I click the link. I need it to trigger every time the loop is running.

```
{% for book in books %}
   {{ book.isbn }}
{% endfor %}
```

I want to get {{ book.isbn }}, so that I can process it and output another variable based on that value. I also want to do this for every "book" value inside the books list, therefore, I can't manually do this elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you pass your function as a keyword argument in your render method it should do the trick.

```
from jinja2 import Template

template = Template("""
{% for book in books %}
   {{ custom_function(book.isbn) }}
{% endfor %}
""")

from collections import namedtuple
Book = namedtuple('Book', ['name', 'isbn'])

books = [
        Book('a', 1),
        Book('b', 2),
        Book('c', 3)
        ]

def custom_function(isbn):
    return isbn + 1

print(template.render(books=books, custom_function=custom_function))
```